# glossary does not appear

Tags: indexing, glossaries

I've placed

```
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
```

just before

```
\begin{document}
```

as recommended in my preamble. After the main part of my paper I've placed

```
\newpage
\printglossaries
\newpage
```

before

```
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

But the glossary won't appear. Here is what I do:

1. Run `LaTeX` to load my document
2. Run `BibTex` to load my bibliography
3. Run `LaTeX` to generate citations and references

Before 3. I tried to run `MakeIndex` but then I got the following message:

```
Couldn't find input index file MainV2 nor MainV2.idx.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]
```

What do I do wrong?

I use TeXShop Version 2.43 on Mac OS 10.7., if that matters.

Comment: Run MakeIndex in a terminal like: `makeindex -s MainV2.ist -t MainV2.glg -o MainV2.gls MainV2.glo` (or simply `makeglossaries MainV2` if makeglossaries is available in your system) and finally run (pdf)latex again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run

1. Run `LaTeX` to load my document
2. Run `makeglossaries` to load my Glossaries
3. Run `LaTeX` to generate citations and references

Comment: `makeglossaries` was not implemented in my `TeXShop`. But still after implementation my glossary won't appear. I run `LaTeX`, then `makeglossaries` and get back the following message:
`This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2010] (kpathsea + Thai support). Scanning style file ./MainV2.ist...........................done (27 attributes redefined, 0 ignored). Scanning input file ./MainV2.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Nothing written in ./MainV2.gls. Transcript written in ./MainV2.glg.`
By the way: I put all glossary-entries in a separate tex-file (Glossary.tex).