# Problems with implementing glossary.engine in TeXShop

Tags: indexing, glossaries

I followed the instruction from [Creating Glossaries in TeXShop on Mac](http://the-moni-blog.blogspot.de/2009/10/creating-glossaries-in-texshop-on-mac.html) but the created engine did not appear (even not with Emacs). Here is what I did:

I created `glossary_run.engine` with `TextEdit` (and later also with Emacs):

```
#!/bin/sh

bfname=$(dirname "$1")/"`basename "$1" .tex`"

makeindex -s "$bfname".ist -t "$bfname".alg -o "$bfname".acr "$bfname".acn
makeindex -s "$bfname".ist -t "$bfname".glg -o "$bfname".gls "$bfname".glo
```

I saved the file in `/Applications/TeX/TeXShop.app/Contents/Resources/TeXShop` and then run

```
chmod a+x glossary_run.engine
```

in `Terminal`, started `TeXShop`but could not find `glossary_run` in the dropdown-menu. Has anyone an idea what went wrong?

Comment: When I have done this in the past, I placed the `.engine` file in `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines` not in the actual `.app` wrapper, and you need to exit and re-launch `TeXShop`.

Comment: Now the engine appears in the dropdown-menu. But still the glossary won't appear: I first compiled my document MainV2.tex with `LaTeX` and then with `glossary_run`. I got the following message:

`This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2010] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file ./MainV2.ist...........................done (27 attributes redefined, 0 ignored).
Scanning input file ./MainV2.glo...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in ./MainV2.gls.
Transcript written in ./MainV2.glg.`

By the way: I put all glossary-entries in a separate tex-file (Glossary.tex).

Comment: Did you re-run `LaTex` again after `glossary_run`?

Comment: Yes, several times.

Comment: OK, but that seems to be unrelated to this question. Please post a separate question including a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: please the http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49054/glossary-does-not-appear for my second problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .engine file should be placed in

```
~/Library/TeXShop/Engines
```

not in the actual .app wrapper, and you need to exit and re-launch `TeXShop`.

After this the `glossary_run` command will appear in the pull down menu.